# Segmentation Fault when sending a simple mail from Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, osx-lion, rvm

So I'm not quite sure what to do here.

I've got a simple application that's basically done, it's main purpose is to collect RSVPs for  a wedding. I set up a simple Mailer to notify me whenever a new RSVP is entered, which looks like in the log it works. However whenever I actually tell it to perform deliveries in dev, there's a segmentation fault and the rails server crashes. I posted a bug in the rails project over on github, and they said it's something to do with my interaction with OpenSSL, which I didn't think I was using. (this is a from scratch rails 3.2 app, nothing special or weird configuration wise)

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'gmail.com' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :domain               => 'gmail.com',
    :port                 => 587,
    :user_name            => 'user@gmail.com',
    :password             => 'secret',
    :authentication       => 'plain',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

it produces a giant log, which is posted over at github: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5115

So I'm not sure where to go from here. I installed the openssl package from rvm, which successfully built and installed, and I also tried removing `enable_starttls_auto` from the config file at the github suggestion, but it just keeps crashing.

I'm running Ruby 1.9.3-p0 through RVM, and rails 3.2.0 on OS X Lion

Comment: Have you tried running in JRuby? It might not still work, but it will hopefully give you a better idea why it is failing.

Comment: I've never used JRuby before, but I can give it a shot I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up following the instructions here: [Lion: Problem with RVM installing rubies - problem related to openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533163/lion-problem-with-rvm-installing-rubies-problem-related-to-openssl) and got ruby working with open SSL. The mail sent successfully and no longer has any problems with crashing the server. Hooray!

Answer (score 0):

They are correct that the issues is with Rails' interaction with OpenSSL. This post sums it up amazingly well. http://www.22ideastreet.com/debug/smtp-rb14-bug-segmentation-fault/

The fix is to add this to your .bashrc/.zshrc/.bash_profile

```
export RUBYOPT="-ropenssl"
```